# Number of pairs of numbers with difference at least K

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, time

Given `n`, the number of terms in the array and `k`, a positive number and an array `arr[]`, it is expected to find the number of pairs in the array such that their difference is at least `k`.
EX:
INPUT

```
7 2  
2 4 3 5 6 1 7
```

OUTPUT

```
15
```

So my approach was:

```
int main()
{
   long long int n,k;
   scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&k);
   long long int a=0,arr[n];
   while(a<n)
   {
    scanf("%lld",&arr[a]);
    a++;
   }
   quicksort(arr,0,n-1);//sorting the array
   long long int i=n-1,j=0,ans=0;//two-pointer method
   while(i>0)
   {
    if(arr[i] - arr[j] >= k && j < i)
    {
        ans ++;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
        j = 0;
    }
   }
   printf("%lld",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

But the solution exceeds time limit for larger test cases. Any improvements possible?

Comment: The worst case time complexity of quicksort can be O(n^2). Try submitting with a better sorting algorithm.

Comment: There are 5 pairs. Why 15?

Comment: (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (2,7) etc.

Comment: @JamesBrown But the difference of (2,5), (2,6), (2,7) is not 2. Then...?

Comment: But it is _at least_ 2.

Comment: Oh! I understand. Didn't notice the "_at least_" part.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of binary search in this problem. After sorting the array, you can find pairs with difference more than `K` for each element `x` by [binary searching](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) for `K+x`. After finding the index `i` where the elements after it all have value equal or more than `K+x` you can easily solve the problem.

```
total = 0
sort(arr)
for each x in arr:
   i = lower_bound(K+x)
   total += arr.size - i
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you only ever increment the answer by 1. After sorting the array, I would run two index variables from the bottom. Increase the upper index until the elements' difference is >= `k`. Then I know that the difference with all the following elements is also >= `k` so can add the remaining length of the array to the answer. Then increase the bottom index, again adding the length of the remaining array until the difference is < `k`. So the bottom index chases the top index along the array, only a single pass is required.

Answer (score 1):

Improvements can be made in while loop. You're searching for all the elements that satisfy the given condition. We can take advantage of the sort by just searching for one element (say b, Since arr[i] + k <= b), the subsequent elements would then always satisfy the condition, thus reducing the searches made.

```
int n,k;
cin>>n>>k;
std::vector<int> v(n,0);

for(int i = 0;i < n;++i)
    cin>>v[i];

sort(v.begin(),v.end()); 

std::vector<int> ::iterator it;
int result = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
    int a = v[i];
    it = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),a+k); // find the element that satisfies a + k <= b
    if(it != v.end())
        result += n - (it - v.begin()); // number of elements which are more than b
}

cout<<result<<"\n";
```